# We throw a fair die 3 times.Find the probability to bring two times the same number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

We throw a die(fair) $3$ times.Find the probability to have two times the same number.

solution:i think $$\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\cdot 6=\frac{1}{36}$$
Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: What you have calculated is the probability of having three times the same number. Only two times is quite a bit more common.

Comment: yea i just realised it.i think two times the same its a bit more complicated.

Comment: I actually think that the easiest is to calculate 1) the probability of all different, 2) the probability of three equal. Then every case that's left has two equal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we write the results of the throws on a paper, then here's how you can calculate all good combinations. Choose a random number (6 choices) and then write that number in two of places $(\binom{3}{2} = 3$ choices) And for the remaining number you can choose any of the rest $5$ numbers. Hence:

$$\text{Good Combinations} = 6  \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 90$$

Divide this by the number of all possible combinations and you will get the final probability.

The previous method is to find the probability if you want the same number appearing exactly twice. If a good combination means that a number is appearing at least twice then find all bad combinations ($6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 120$ choices) and subtract that number from all the combinations to get the number of good combinations and eventually find the probability of that happening.

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the probability to have EXACTLY two times the same number:
there are 6 ways to choose the value of the couple, 3 ways to assign them to the 3 dice (xxo,xox,oxx), and 5 ways to choose the third value (different form the couple). Hence
$$p=\frac{6\cdot 3 \cdot 5 }{6^3}=\frac{15}{36}=\frac{5}{12}.$$

2) Find the probability to have AT LEAST two times the same number: just add to the previous cases the 6 triples with the same value.
Hence
$$p=\frac{6\cdot 3 \cdot 5 +6}{6^3}=\frac{15+1}{36}=\frac{4}{9}.$$

Comment: Why is ist not $p= \frac{6\cdot 3 \cdot 6}{6^3}=0.5$ in the second case?

Comment: @Philipp $6\cdot 3\cdot 5=90$ counts the number of ways where 2 values of dice are equal and the third is distinct like $(5,5,3)$, $(3,5,5)$ or $(4,5,4)$. If the 3 dice have the same value there are only 6 cases (not $6\cdot 3\cdot 1=18$): $(1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2)$,...,$(6,6,6)$.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that point.